# Is u_char a standard?

Tags: c

Just curious if u_char is a standard.  I've always used it assuming it was defined along with uintX_t types and so on.  But am seeing some of our code base transition from u_char to "unsigned char" with a reason "so users don't have to define u_char themselves"..

Comment: u_char is not part of the official ANSI C Standard

Comment: what about #include <cstdint> & typedef uint8_t u_char; ?

Answer (score 15):

The string `u_char` does not appear in this draft of the C standard:

http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/WG14/www/docs/n1256.pdf

It's not required by POSIX either, as far as I know.

I think it's in BSD (sys/types.h), and Windows (winsock.h). I would not consider either one to be "a standard" - they aren't formal standards, and they certainly aren't part of standard C, but they are clearly defined and documented.

Comment: Moreover the problem of using these ugly nonstandard types is that you have to be very careful about defining them. Some systems will already have them defined (which is wrong), leading to errors if you define them yourself, but others will not, meaning you can't use the type unless you define it yourself. The safest way is just not to use junk like this, not be lazy, and write out `unsigned char` when you mean it.

Comment: @R.. or use `<stdint.h>` for the `uint8_t`, ... types.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart: using `uint8_t` in effect has an in-built assertion that `CHAR_BIT == 8`, since the type is forbidden to exist if `CHAR_BIT > 8`. That's fine if you want an 8 bit type, but if what you mean is "an unsigned integer type occupying one unit of storage in this implementation, whatever that may be", then you should say that: `unsigned char`.

Answer (score 11):

No, `u_char` is non-standard.  If you need to use a standard type that's equivalent to `u_char`, you can use `uint8_t` which is part of the C99 standard library (check your specific platforms/compilers for C99-compliance).  `stdint.h` defines this type (along with many other specific integral types).  [This Wikipedia article contains more information about `stdint.h`.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stdint.h)

Answer (score 4):

It's not present in any older header files (except certain specific areas, like Kerberos and networking headers), and not a built-in type in any compiler I know of.