# How do I detect "\r\n" in a u_char type buffer?

Tags: c, http

I am trying to construct HTTP content from packet sniffing using C.  Right now, I am able to save all of the packets in a file but I want to get rid of the headers in the first packet.  The headers are also being saved because they are a part of the TCP payload.  The actual body after the header starts after a double "CR, LF" or `"\r\n\r\n"` in the HTTP response.

How do I detect `"\r\n"` so that I can save only the part of the buffer that follows it?  The buffer is u_char type.  I can't figure out the command.  I looked on Google and other places, but I mostly find C# commands - nothing in C.

i am using this function

```
void strtofcntnt(const u_char * Biffer, int size)
{
unsigned short iphdrlen;
struct iphdr *iph = (struct iphdr *)(Buffer + sizeof(struct ethhdr));
iphdrlen = iph->ihl*4;
```

`struct tcphdr *tcph = (struct tcphdr*)(Buffer + iphdrlen + sizeof(struct ethhdr))`;

```
char data[] = *(Buffer);
char rdata[] = strstr(data, "\r\n\r\n");
unsigned int i;
for (i=0;i<=sizeof(data);i++)
{
fprintf(logfile,"%c",(unsigned int)data[i]);
}}
```

but it gives error in the chara data[] and char rdata[] lines during compiling. error says invalid initializer.

Comment: Did you even *read* my answer? `strstr` is not going to work on binary data that includes null bytes. Also, use `char* data`.

Comment: "I looked on Google" -- Google can help you get an education, but it isn't a substitute for one. Learn a programming language, then write programs in that language, not the other way around (other than programs used as course material).

Answer (score 6):

`u_char` is [not a standard datatype](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1918934/is-u-char-a-standard).  You should look in the header the defines it, but certainly it is just an `unsigned char`.

Since the data can have null bytes embedded in it, [`strstr`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strstr) will not work to find the `"\r\n\r\n"`.  You'll have to write some sort of search method:

```
const char* memsearch(const char* haystack, size_t haystack_len,
                const char* needle, size_t needle_len)
{
    const char* p;

    for (p = haystack; p < (haystack + haystack_len - needle_len); p++) {
        if (memcmp(p, needle, needle_len) == 0)
            return p;
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

Comment: now the problem is when i compile it with gcc it gives error in char data[] line and char rdata[] line as error : invalid initializer

Comment: Sorry, I can't hold your hand through the entire development process. You asked how to find `"\r\n\r\n"` in binary data, and I provided a solution. I'm not trying to be harsh, that's just the way this site works: clear, concise questions get clear, concise answers.  If you have another problem, that you can't solve *after doing research on your own*, then please post another question.

Comment: memmem() migh actualy work what i was actually lookin for. Thank u!!